# Предлагаю объединить метки “деепричастие” и “деепричастия”

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Предлагаю объединить метки “деепричастие” и “деепричастия”. Мы отдаем предпочтение множественному числу. Тогда пусть метка “деепричастия” будет главной, а “деепричастие” – синонимом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь! Метки объединены, синонимы созданы.